# How to recognize if object is on the stack or heap memory

Tags: c++, list, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have recently received a university assignment for my Data Structures course, which requires me to create a **doubly linked list** in **C++**.

While working on my doubly linked list, I needed to implement various functionalities, but one method that particularly caught my attention is named **"clear()"**. This method is responsible for **clearing all elements** within the doubly linked list:

```
void clear(Node* head_ptr)
{
    Node* previous_ptr = nullptr;

    while(head_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        previous_ptr = head_ptr; // Store previous node.

        head_ptr = head_ptr->next;

        delete previous_ptr;
    }
};
```

The method is quite straightforward; it simply iterates through all elements and deallocates the memory for each `Node`. I then **invoke this method within my destructor** as follows:

```
~List()
{
    clear_list(m_head_ptr);
};
```

Then I got to thinking. This method of freeing memory is fine **if my node elements are on the heap**, like this:

```
int main()
{
    List list;

    Node* node_1 = new Node(3, nullptr);    // The tail node.
    Node* node_2 = new Node(1, node_1);
    Node* node_3 = new Node(5, node_2);
    Node* node_4 = new Node(7, node_3);     // The head node. 
    
    list.add(node_1);
    list.add(node_2);
    list.add(node_3);
    list.add(node_4);

    // Then do some stuff with the list...

}   // The list goes out of scope and the destructor is called...
```

But, this breaks as soon as I create **the `Node`s on the stack** and pass a pointer to stack objects, like this:

```
int main()
{
    List list;

    Node* node_1(3, nullptr);    // The tail node.
    Node* node_2(1, node_1);
    Node* node_3(5, node_2);
    Node* node_4(7, node_3);     // The head node. 
    
    list.add(&node_1);
    list.add(&node_2);
    list.add(&node_3);
    list.add(&node_4);

    // Then do some stuff with the list...

}   // The list goes out of scope and the destructor is called and the program crashes because it attempts to free stack objects...
```

The reason is **because I am attempting to free stack objects which is not a good idea**. Naturally, we wouldn't normally use stack-based `Node`s because we typically want our `Node` data to persist beyond the scope in which they are created. Nevertheless, this leads me to my question:

How do I counter this? Is there a way to check **if some `Node` in memory is on the heap or the stack in my function** and then free it accordingly? Or, is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: _this breaks as soon as I create the Nodes on the stack_ so don't do that!

Comment: Does `Node* node_1(3, nullptr);` compile? It should be `Node` instead. Also grab a book about how dynamic memory allocation is done in C++ from the [booklist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4123703) is better. When you `new` it, you're responsible to `delete` it. If you don't new it, why do you need to delete it?

Comment: It is undefined behavior to use free() or delete() if you did not first use a matching malloc() or new().  If you did use malloc or new then the object is on the heap.  So, you are asking how to not randomly delete() something not created with new() ?    Code should never  free or delete something it has no idea about how it was created.    Mixing malloc/delete and new/free will also mess up your program even though they are both heap.

Comment: The concept to control that is an _Allocator_ class like it's used for `std::vector` and other standard containers.

Comment: Practically, this is next-to-impossible to reliably determine in the general case. And I'm not even go to the "There might not even **BE** a stack or Heap!" case. Let's assume you have stacks and heaps. On some systems you'll know exactly where the stack is and its length so you can check whether or not the pointer is in range, but that will be a, by modern standards, astoundingly simple system. A modern desktop is far from simple. For example, Every thread in a process will have its own stack. That's potentially a lot of book-keeping to know them all even if the OS advertises the locations.

Comment: Your code doesn't adhere to the C++ Core Guidelines, and that's why you are stuck in this mess. [R.3: A raw pointer (a T*) is non-owning](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning). But your code uses a raw pointer for sometimes-owning (`new Node()`) and sometimes-not-owning (Node on the stack).  It also breaks rule [R.11: Avoid calling `new` and `delete` explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly). Your `add` method should accept a `std::unique_ptr<Node>`.

Comment: Also, detecting whether the address is on a stack (there could be more than one) or heap is the wrong question. `struct Bonus { int bonus; Node node; }; Bonus* bonus = new Bonus(); list.add(&bonus->node);` This "node' is on the heap, but you still shouldn't `delete` it. Really, the question is "How do I keep track of who is responsible for freeing this memory?" C++ has a number for techniques for this, such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: If done professionally, The API documentation will explicitly say how an object passed by raw pointer is to be destroyed if it is to be manually destroyed. If you are writing the API and you are passing around raw pointers and the user has to manually manage its lifetime, it's on **you** to document how.

Comment: The first code is messy but workable. The second code seems to be an imaginary problem that you imagine about the implementation.  `Node* node_1(3, nullptr);` doesn't even compile, and even if does, it is not a node on the stack. `Node node_1(3, nullptr);` could compile, but of course the whole thing will not work because ownership will not be clear. Either the list owns the nodes or it doesn't. Things in the stack are owned by the stack.

Comment: You may refer to *More Effective C++* Item 27: *Requiring or prohibiting heap-based objects.*

Comment: Use raw pointers as **non-owning** pointers.  Use `std::unique_ptr` as an *owning* smart pointer, and in particular when passing ownership or returning ownership.  (Only use `std::shared_ptr` if you really have to.)

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem created by you. May be you would be better off not creating such a problem: the only way to add nodes to the list is by calling `add` . So use only owning-pointers. In `add` copy the data the user passed in to a newly allocated node. This way you know who created every node and you know how and when to delete one. And understand that a list is not a node and a node is not a list. And a node is not the data,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest and most effective solution is *usually* for the list to manage allocation of nodes itself. The user shouldn't even need to be aware that a `node` type exists, not to mention allocating them and such.

So, to the user, the equivalent of what you show in the question would be something like this:

```cpp
List list;
list.add_head(1);
list.add_head(3);
list.add_head(5);
list.add_head(7);
```

You'd typically also have an `add_tail` to add items to the end of the list. Each `add` (head or tail) should normally return an abstract `iterator` type (which will probably be a wrapper around a pointer to a node), so you can do something like:

```cpp
auto pos = list.add_head(7);
list.add_tail(5);
list.add_after(pos, 3);
```

...which would add 7 at the beginning, 5 at the end, and `3` just after the `7`.

This way, the list itself allocates all the nodes, and knows how to dispose of them. You might go a step further, and have it delegate allocation and disposal to an `Allocator` class. That can certainly be useful, but may be a bit beyond what makes sense for basically an exercise (in practical use, you probably want to use a container from the standard library--and while the standard library does provide both singly- and doubly-linked lists, they're *rarely* useful).

Comment: So, essentially the solution is to declare the Node class as a private member of my List class and disable the ability to create individual nodes from outside the class? However,   every programmer keeps suggesting to me that placing classes in their dedicated files is a preferred practice. Is there a way to define a class in a separate file while ensuring it remains visible and accessible exclusively to a specific class?

Comment: @Default a class-per-file is a nice, orderly way of doing things, but sometimes it's the wrong way to go. Think of the header as a description of an interface, and the less of the nitty-gritty, back-end details you expose in the interface the better because it reduces your ability to change the interface in the future.  The node class, something that is tightly coupled to the linked list class that uses it, might as well be in the same header. And since there are significant benefits to hiding the node class from the user, it should be inside the linked list class and kept out of sight.

Comment: There is also often a case to be made for only declaring the node in the header and totally hiding it by placing the definition in a compiled implementation file so no one other than the linked list implementation can mess with it or make assumptions about it. But that can wait until your course material reaches "Opaque Pointers" and the "PIMPL idiom".

Comment: @Default: For a case like this, the only thing you'll probably need in the header is a declaration of the node class, like: `class node;`. That's enough to let you do the other things the header needs to do--mostly `List` containing: `node *head;` (and possibly `node *tail;`). Other than that, `node` is an implementation detail, so it can live entirely inside `List.cpp` (or, if you really want to, create a separate `node.hpp` just for it--but I don't see that as a win.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just now learning about dynamic memory, you have to learn from the ground up (someone has to write the libraries - someday that could be you!).

So, one reason you would ever use a linked list is because you do not know how many nodes will be added ahead of time.  Similarly, implementations of putting a "MAX_SIZE" on their linked lists w/stack based node data are not good (is MAX_SIZE big enough? is it too big for some clients of your linked list?)

Hence, linked lists are almost always implemented using dynamic memory.  In C, that would be malloc/free.  In C++, that would be new/delete.  Eventually, client code would utilize standard library templatized implementations (like many are pointing you to).

So to answer your question, at this point in your education, use dynamic memory using new/delete exclusively for your linked list nodes.

You will soon learn WHY you (will eventually) use standard library implementations as you have to learn about all the edge cases when using/manipulating hand-made linked lists (dereferencing deleted pointers, memory leaks, et. al.).

Many times, you learn more by failure (e.g. how to use a debugger!).

Comment: Thank you for encouraging me!

Comment: "I have recently received a university assignment for my Data Structures course" provided the right context for my answer.